# SQLAlchemy - bulk update objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulkupdate

I'm attempting to do a bulk update with sqlalchemy.

What does work, is selecting the objects to update, then setting the attributes inside of a `with session.begin_nested():` statement. The time it takes to do the actual save is slow, however.

When I attempt to use a bulk operation instead via `session.bulk_save_objects` or `session.bulk_update_mappings` I get the following exception:

```
A value is required for bind parameter 'schema_table_table_id' 
[SQL: u'UPDATE schema.table SET updated_col=%(updated_col)s 
 WHERE schema.table.table_id = %(schema_table_table_id)s'] 
 [parameters: [{'updated_col': 'some_val'}]]
```

It looks like `bulk_save_objects` uses the same logic path as `bulk_update_mappings`.

I actually don't even understand how `bulk_update_mappings` is supposed to work, because you are providing the updated values and a reference class but the primary key associated with those values are missing from your list. That essentially seems to be problem here. I tried using `bulk_update_mappings` and I provided the generated dictionary key used for the primary key param (`schema_table_table_id` in my example) and it just ended up being ignored. If I used the `id` attribute name instead, it would update the primary key in the generated SQL but still did not provide the needed parameter in the where clause.

This is using SQLAlchemy 1.0.12, which is the latest version on pip.

My suspicion is that this is a bug.

Comment: I think it would make sense if you are using autoincrement for your primary key; then the internals of `SQLAlchemy` would decide for you. Maybe it would be easier to help if you gave a few more details: the class for the table you are trying to update, and a minimum example. Thanks.

Comment: You're thinking of insert where the primary key is not required. This is an update though, so you need the primary key in order to know specifically which record you are updating. I'm actually asking for an example. I can figure out whats wrong with my code if I have a working example to check against.

Comment: Sorry for my nonsensical comment, you are right!

Comment: facing the same issue, so little documentation on bulk_update_mappings